# Should read-only fields hide or disable icons?

Tags: usability, icons, input-fields, best-practice, disable

Throughout our system we have different input-field types that have icons tied to them.

**Examples:**

- Time field with a time icon - when clicking the icon it will fill in the current time.
- Date Field with a calendar icon - clicking the calendar will bring up a calendar where the user can select a date.

Is there any best practices for how icons should display on read-only input-fields?

- Should the icons be hidden? OR
- Should they just have a disabled style?

**Example with the icons with disabled style:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Favor disabling over hiding the icons.

**A standard disabled `<select>` input still looks like a `<select>` input when disabled.** This allows the user to expect a certain type of interaction from this element. The entry methods for common elements vary, and the styling helps the user predict which one is expected of them. The following (non-exhaustive) lists help to illustrate the differences in user expectations.

Primary input method: **Click/tap**

- Select lists (usually)
- Checkbox
- Radio button
- Button

Primary input method: **Keyboard entry**

- Input fields

Seeing an element that looks like an input field, then watching it quickly transform into a `<select>` element when it becomes enabled would cause a user to have to briefly reprocess the elements to figure out how to interact with it.

So, following the pattern of the `<select>` item, I'd allow your custom inputs to show their distinct icons so that a user can have a shot at preprocessing them before they become enabled.

Comment: I'd add that while this is about icons, favouring disable over hiding is one of only a very few near-universal best practices in UI design. If possible, always show the UI. Because not showing it risks people never knowing about it.